# @Primary in @Configuration class not working for child class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

I have a class A and class B which extends A. Child class overrides init() method.

```
public class A {
    public A(){

    }

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Inside init method of A");
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    public B(){
        super();
    }

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Inside init method of B");
    }
}
```

I have 2 Configuration annotated classes where I am creating objects of the above classes A and B. MainConfig class creates object of child and the SampleConfig creates object of A. However I have annotated the child class creation with @Primary.

MainConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class MainConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public A createA() {
        return new B(); //Child Class
    }

}
```

SampleConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class SampleConfig {

    @Bean
    public A createA() {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

When i run the application, the child class B is never called or created inspite of being annotated as @Primary.

My aim is to override the init method of the super class.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you named them the same, which will overwrite the beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum you mean the method createA(), right? I dont want object of being created. It should be created as part of super call in B(the child class). In the above example creation of A is being called in SampleConfig and the new B() call in MainConfig is never called even though its annotated as primary. My requirement is to create the Bean A from child class.

Comment: Read... You cannot have beans with the same name only 1 will be created.

Comment: Yes, agreed, but why not the one which is annotated as Primary.

Comment: It depends on loading order, last one wins.

Comment: Thanks for your response @M.Deinum. Is there a way I can control or advise?

Comment: Just don't use the same names and the `@Primary` will be uses. If you want to control ordering use the `@Order` annotation however sometimes that won't work as you not always control the classes (like from 3rd party extensions).